# Wordpress 'Failed to write wp-config' I've done all the Chowns

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, xampp, lampp

I am on a mission to install wp-deploy on my local installation of linux mint. I had a wordpress working in xampp via the bitnami plugin but wp-deploy needed to go to htdocs.  I began getting permission errors like crazy.  I am in day 4 of complete madness which last night resulted in me somehow accidentally corrupting my system files (maybe I chowned myself out of them but i dont think I touched anything besides the lampp folders) and having to reinstall mint so all further actions are taking place on a blank slate.

What I tried before the wipe:

- install wp-deploy in xampp htdocs: Fought permissions so long I forgot all of what I tried but ended up wondering if maybe the issue was xampp so..
- gutted xampp and installed mysql, php, apache2 and phpmyadmin individually. After much debugging it ran and I was able to serve an html file. However when I set up wordpress it did not have access to it’s own directory. Spent a bunch of time Chowning around and it seemed if I got one thing access I denied another thing. Then it all blew up and I got the blue login screen and went into recovery/wipe mode.

### NEW INSTALL ATTEMPTS

To reduce the number of variables I decided I would install regular old wordpress as I do not think the issue is related to wp-deploy.

This is what I've done today:

-Installed Xampp and dragged wordpress into htdocs/myprojectname/
After navigating to localhost/myprojectname/wordpress/wp-admin I was presented with the setup form. Got error ‘failed to write wp-config’

-Chown -R www-data:myuser ./lampp/
Caused mySql to get permission denied error in the xampp control panel

-Gut Xampp, try again
Again, failed to write wp-config so this time I..

-Chowned only the wordpress folder using www-data

-still fails so I restart xampp

-Chowned only the wordpress folder using www-data:myuser

-still I get failed to write wp-config

-Chowned the directory containing the site just inside htdocs as my user

-same error

All of my google-fu takes me to posts that resolve when someone chowns the directory. Either I am experiencing a different error or I am doing something wrong.  I am desperate. Help me obi-wan kenobi. You are my only hope.

-------UPDATE-------

Some other posts recommend building wp-config manually. The reason I haven't been doing this is because the underlying issue I want to solve is that wordpress has not been able to write to it's own folder and therefore cannot install plugins or do anything besides sit there.  I was making the assumption that the wp-config error indicated the same permissions fight I had been in since before the wipe. I decided to manually build wp-config and it was as I thought, wordpress cannot install plugins.

-------UPDATE-------

I have chmod 777ed the directory and still no go.

Comment: I sympathize,  but we can't help you without technical details.   You could start with an `ls -l` on the directories or sample files in question and the desired owner and permissions.

Comment: Two things: are you certain www-data is the name of the server group? In my Mac XAMPP install, it is daemon. Second, you should be chowning user:group and the directory will need to be writeable by group, so myuser:www-data instead of the other way around. Give that a whirl....

Comment: i used a grep to be certain that www-data was indeed the name apache2 was running under.

Comment: Dan Farrell,  drwxr-xr-x  5 root :root is the default permissions of htdocs. Above I explain that I have chowned and chmodded them into many configurations so im not sure what information you are looking for. I took screenshots that I didnt post verifying each of the permissions configurations that I tried. But wouldn't chmod 777 effectively bypass this as a potential problem despite being bad practice for production?

Answer (score 1):

Best to Used LAMP stack instead of XAMMP

Comment: Thank you for the response but I did try that. I was running Xampp -it failed, so I installed LAMP and it failed in the same way.

Comment: what version of WP are you trying to install?

Comment: the most recent one. I went and pulled the zip from wordpress.com.  I've tried several downloads and experienced the same issue with the wp-deploy Installation I pulled from git

Comment: Im curious though, can you be more specific about Lamp over Xampp? I tried both because I thought maybe Xampp had custom magic happening that was making the problem harder to predict, but switching to Lamp did not fix it. It was during the Lamp phase that I somehow killed my install and had to start over and I just went back to Xampp for the ease of it. But understanding the difference might help me tease this apart.

Answer (score 0):

Change ownership and group of your project folder

This will help you to solve the write problem in wp_config.php

```
 1.sudo chown daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/[project_name]
 2.sudo chgrp daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/[project_name]
```